# Scrape User Login after login to external website when running Node.js in browser

Tags: node.js, express, web-scraping

Can I scrape a popup window of a user login to external website after user successfully logged in when running Node.js in the browser (Like how Puppeteer will do it the terminal?)

Comment: please post your current code progress along with the actual output and desired output in question.

Answer (score 0):

here is the codes sample

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
async function login(){

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(100000);
    await page.goto(url, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    });

    await page.waitForSelector("[name='login[username]");
    await page.type("[name='login[username]']", "talenttop044@gmail.com");
    await page.waitForSelector("[name='login[password]");
    await page.type("[name='login[password]']", "D&6^XM#8<]Vn_mjh");

    await page.keyboard.down("Tab");
    await page.keyboard.down('Enter'); 
    await page.waitForNavigation(); 
}
```

Hope this helps you. 
Regards

Comment: Can I use puppeteer if my app is an express.js app running on localhost:3000?

Comment: yes, just install puppeteer using "npm install --save puppeteer" and use puppeteer like my above codes